# Creating an overlay page for app

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am looking into adding a single page overlay when a user clicks the "Help" button in a web app I've created. Below is an example of what I want to achieve

[image: single page overlay]

I have jquery mobile implemented on my pages with javascript. I looked into the jquery mobile popup panels that overlay a page but it wouldn't serve my purposes.

What resources, libraries, language, etc would I go about doing this? I tried to google but the I get irrelevant results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't try it, but you can put the background in a div leaving it in behind the classic background (using low css z-index) with a fixed position (absolute position), a fixed width/height (100%/100%) and a trasparency.

When the user click the "Help" buttons you change the z-index putting it on the front of the page.

**UPDATE**
Assuming a html layout similar like this:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <!-- some others divs with the content of the page and the help link -->
  <a href="#" id="help_button">HELP</a>
 </div>
 <div id="over_image"> <!-- add this -->
  <img src="path_to_the_overlapping_image" alt="overlap image" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A default CSS like this

```
div#container {
 z-index: 100;
}

div#over_image {
 z-index: -100; // by default the over image is "behind" the page
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%; // or puts the width/height of the "screen" in pixels
 height: 100%;
}

div#over_image img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity:0.4;
 filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

And at the end the jQuery function

```
$("a#help_button").on("click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); // it's not really a link
 $("div#over_image").css("z-index", "1000");
})
```

You should implement the "hide" function too, to "reset" the overlapping image on some action, maybe something like this:

```
$("div#over_image img").on("click", function(){
 // when the user click on the overlap image, it disappears
 $("div#over_image").css("z-index", "-100");
})
```

I haven't try it, maybe there are some more little things to change to make it works correctly, but it is a good begin.

**SOME REFERENCES**

- Opacity / transparency: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp
- jQuery css: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Would be nice to post any practical example, it's a doubt that I also have!

Comment: @Evandro I have updated my answer, as I say, maybe there are some more little things to change to make it work correctly (I haven't tested it)

Comment: I'm interested in this topic as well, but I think the question owner should accept it. But looking at the code you sent, seem that works as he expects. Did you take this example from somewhere? If so, could share with us? thanks!!

Comment: @Evandro sorry but I have written the example "from my mind" ;) I have put some reference links that can be helpful for playing with transparency and jQuery.

Comment: Seems to do what you intended @damoiser and hence awarding you the best answer. I also used jquery mobile overlay panel, which works fine too. the issue (across both solutions) is the image doesn't resize when the window changes. so when you're using that to do a "app tutorial" with arrows pointing at buttons and whatnot its a problem as the arrows point at something completely different on window change. Thanks for your answer!